# Eclipse => same shortcuts as Visual Studio?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to set Eclipse to have the same shortcuts as Visual Studio?  F5 starts the debugger, shift-F5 stops the debugger, F9 sets a breakpoint, F10 steps over, F11 steps into.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Window->Preferences->General->Keys

Now search for the following commands, and have them as follows:

[image: key shortcuts to be set]

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to **Window > Preferences**.

From the open the **General** branch and select **Keys**.

There you can set the preferred keys by filtering the action you want, and setting up the new key in the **Binding** text box.